# Is the 4D Minkowski spacetime a physical and/or mathematical necessity?

Tags: special-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, inertial-frames

I want to know the physical and mathematical justification for formulating Special Relativity in terms of a four-dimensional pseudo-Euclidean space with metric $\mathrm{d}s^2=c^2\mathrm{d}t^2-\mathrm{d}x^2-\mathrm{d}y^2-\mathrm{d}z^2=\eta_{\mu \nu}\mathrm{d}x^{\mu}\mathrm{d}x^{\nu}$. I mean, one could do Special Relativity in a non-manifestly covariant way, similar to Newtonian mechanics, with ordinary Euclidean vectors in $ℝ^3$ and just having the formulas corrected to account for relativistic effects, and obtain relativistically correct results.

Comment: If we instead lived in Newton's universe with invariant $\mathrm{d}x^2+\mathrm{d}y^2+\mathrm{d}z^2$, you could do something that manifestly ignores the full symmetry by treating $z$ separately. Would that be a reason to doubt 3D Euclidean space is a physical and/or mathematical necessity?

Comment: What would the benefits of doing it your proposed way be? Having co-/contravariance built in to the math is seen as a big plus by the researchers I've worked with.

Comment: I'm not sure what the question here is - one can often do math without explicitly referring to the mathematical structure (e.g. one could also talk about Lorentz transformations without ever mentioning that they form a group or that they are linear transformations on Minkowski space - does that mean the Lorentz group is "not a mathematical necessity"? What does that even mean?).  Why do you need a "justification" for using a particular mathematical framework other than that it *works*?

Answer (score 1):

The invariant formulation involving $\eta_{\mu\nu}dx^\mu dx^\nu$ takes advantage of the symmetry that is inherent in special relativity. (Analogously, in a free-body diagram we think in terms of force vectors and vector operations to exploit symmetries, rather than working with components [which can sometimes obscure the physics]. Or we think of a electric vector field, rather than a set of component fields.)

Another example... nowadays we use [Maxwell's Equations in vector form (formulated by Heaviside)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Maxwell%27s_equations) , rather than the system of partial differential equations that Maxwell first wrote down.

So, it's not wrong to do it non-covariantly. In some cases, it might be better or easier to understand.

However, in likely many more situations (which may not all be of interest to you), it might be very difficult to get intuition about what is going on viewing through a non-covariant-lens.

To me, noting the analogies between Minkowskian spacetime geometry and Euclidean geometry is very helpful and may be fruitful in uncovering more about Special Relativity. That viewpoint is lost thinking in terms of "moving boxcars".